# Server 2012 & Exchange 2013 For Dummies

Tags: windows, exchange, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013

I have had success setting up Windows Server 2012 Standard as a domain controller, and have installed Exchange 2013 to test the software.

However, I am clearly not setting it up with best practice, as my Outlook clients are asking that the certificate isn't secure... etc.

I've searched so many sites and help topics - but I am wondering if anyone knows of a "Dummies Guide" style site that can explain exactlt the whole process of setting up a new domain controller, exchange server, forwarding ports, setting up certificates, the whole deal.

Thanks.

Comment: This is for external clients use - say 1-5 user sites. Please help with some suggestions.

Comment: Trying to replace SBS2011 with the new 2012.

Comment: Get a non-dummy. This is not a task for rank amateurs.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, don't put Exchange on a DC. Ever.

Second of all, there's no "guide" that will effectively cover this whole process. In fact, there are entire books on the proper configuration of AD, and even more books on Exchange.

Comment: So with the new Server 2012 that doesn't come with Exchange built in - as SBS2011 did - what would you suggest?

Comment: You should have a server dedicate to Exchange in all but the smallest environments. SBS comes with a lot of stuff built in to keep the cost low and keep it simple for low-tech people to use, but that doesn't make it a good idea.